# C# List<T> internals

Tags: c#, generics, list

What exactly happens when adding an object to a collection such as List?

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
Person dan = new Person() { Name="daniel", Age=10 };
people.Add(dan);
dan = new Person() { Name = "hw", Age = 44 };
```

When I execute the above code, the `List<Person> people`does not get affected by final line.
So I am assuming that the list *copies* the *references* of the added object, so when change the reference, the list does not get affected. am I correct?

Comment: where you add an object to list? can you fix your code?

Comment: oops! forgot to add an object. thankfully, the bright minds of stackoverflow understood what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the code you've shown doesn't actually add anything to the list at all. I assume you meant to have:

```
people.Add(dan);
```

in there somewhere?

But yes, the `List<T>` contains references to objects. It doesn't know about where the references have come from. It's worth being clear about the difference between a variable and its value. When you call:

```
people.Add(dan);
```

that copies the value of the argument expression (`dan`) in this case as the initial value of the parameter within `List<T>.Add`. That value is just a reference - it has no association with the `dan` variable, other than it happened to be the value of the variable at the time when `List<T>.Add` was called.

It's exactly the same as the following situation:

```
Person p1 = new Person { Name = "Jon" };
p2 = p1;
p1 = new Person { Name = "Dan" };
```

Here, the value of `p2` will still be a reference to the person with the name "Jon" - the second line just copies the value of `p1` to `p2` rather than associating the two variables together. Once you understand this, you can apply the same logic to method arguments.

Comment: In the p1 and p2 example you have given, the only reason Person "Jon" continues to exist is because of the p2 = p1 assignment, correct?  If that assignment had not been there, then the creation of "Dan" would have wiped out the instance of "Jon" by GC, if I am correct?  Thanks.

Comment: @Sabuncu: Well, it's not really the creation of "Dan" that "wipes out" the other one - it's the fact that there would be no more references to keep the other object alive. (There's nothing to say *when* the other one would be collected, mind you.) It's worth separating out the creation of another object from the GC aspect. It's not like one replaces the other, for example.

Comment: Thank you!  Was a simple question but I knew the answer, coming from you, would be a learning experience.

Answer (score 4):

Well with *that* code the `List<Person> people` should not get affected by the 2nd line either.

Anyway, the `List<Person>` gets a reference if you use `.Add()` so if you modify that person later, the person in the list is "modified" too (it's the same person), but if you assign the person to someone else you're not affecting the reference, you're assigning the symbol to a new reference.

e.g.:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>(); 
Person dan = new Person() { Name="daniel", Age=10 }; 
people.Add(dan);

/* DanData = { Name="daniel", Age=10 }; 
 * `people[0]` maps to "DanData"
 * `dan` maps to "DanData" */

dan.Name = "daniel the first";
string dansNameInList = people[0].Name; /* equals "daniel the first" */

/* DanData = { Name="daniel the first", Age=10 }; 
 * `people[0]` maps to "DanData"
 * `dan` maps to "DanData" */

people[0].Name = "daniel again";
string dansName = dan.Name /* equals "daniel again" */

/* DanData = { Name="daniel again", Age=10 }; 
 * `people[0]` maps to "DanData"
 * `dan` maps to "DanData" */

dan = new Person() { Name = "hw", Age = 44 }; 
string dansNameInListAfterChange = people[0].Name /* equals "daniel again" */
string dansNameAfterChange = dan.Name /* equals "hw" */

/* DanData = { Name="daniel again", Age=10 }; 
 * NewData = { Name = "hw", Age = 44 }; 
 * `people[0]` maps to "DanData"
 * `dan` maps to "NewData" */
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, assuming you intended to add the person to the list before calling the third line:

Yes, the list only stores a reference to the object.  In C#, *ALL* object variables are references.

So when you call `new Person()` a second time, the reference held by your variable `dan` is updated to point to the new instance.  If the first instance has no reference pointed to it, it will be garbage collected in the next round.  If you had added the first instance to the list, the list would still retain it's reference to the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's important in .NET programming to have a good understanding of the difference between reference types and value types. This article provides a good overview:
http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

In this case, you created two Person objects (Daniel, age 10, and hw, age 44). It's the variables that reference the two objects that created the confusion.

---

```
Person dan = new Person() { Name="daniel", Age=10 };
```

Here, a local variable, dan, is assigned a reference to the newly created (Daniel, age 10) object.

---

```
people.Add(dan);
```

Here, the property people[0] is (indirectly via the List.Add method) assigned a reference to the existing (Daniel, age 10) object.

---

```
dan = new Person() { Name = "hw", Age = 44 };
```

Here, the local variable, dan, is assigned a reference to the newly created (hw, age 44) object. But the property people[0] still holds a reference to the existing (Daniel, age 10) object.

Answer (score 0):

Adding at the end of your code

```
people[0] = dan;
```

would point to your new dan object.